# binding chart to data

Tags: wpf, charts, binding, livecharts

I am workinng with a library called [LiveCharts](https://lvcharts.net/). My goal is to display a chart of dynamic data vs time, (for example, the amount of money I own).
I hava seen the [tutorial and examples](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/wpf/start); but, I couldn't understand how to bind my data automatically!

Is it possible to use LiveCharts to create a dynamic chart from data in a .NET [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604) so that the chart changes whenever the data in the collection changes?

Comment: What's wrong with the "constant changes" example?: https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Constant%20Changes%20II. It demonstrates how to update the chart dynamically by adding double values to a GearedValues<double>().

Comment: `NoisyCollection` https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts/blob/master/Core40/Helpers/NoisyCollection.cs is the equivalent to .Net ObservableCollection, the library could work with observable collections, actually in the first version of the library it used them, right now for performance and thread-safe issues, I decided to implement my own collection.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you don't need an `ObservableCollection` because `LiveCharts.ChartValues` is already observable and will notify when an item will be added.

In this example you can see that when the `RandomizeChartCommand` is invoked, the chart will automatically change due to its binding.

**Packages.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="2.0.4" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="LiveCharts" version="0.9.7" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="LiveCharts.Wpf" version="0.9.7" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="MvvmLightLibs" version="5.4.1" targetFramework="net471" />
</packages>
```

**ViewModel** (I installed the NuGet library `MvvmLightLibs` to get the `RelayCommand` implementation):

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public SeriesCollection ChartData { get; }
    private readonly ChartValues<double> _ys;

    public ICommand RandomizeChartCommand { get; }
    private static Random _random;

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        RandomizeChartCommand = new RelayCommand(RandomizeChart);
        _random = new Random();

        _ys = new ChartValues<double>();

        ChartData = new SeriesCollection()
        {
            new LineSeries() {  Values = _ys }
        };
    }

    public void RandomizeChart()
    {
        _ys.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            _ys.Add(_random.NextDouble() * 100);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
        Title="Test chart" Height="450" Width="800">

    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">

        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="10" >
            <Button Content="Randomize" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="20, 10" Command="{Binding RandomizeChartCommand}" />
        </StackPanel>

        <lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding ChartData}" />

    </DockPanel>

</Window>
```

As you can see if you try this example, when you edit `_ys` collection (add or remove elements), the chart will update.

Comment: chart does not seem to update when editing _ys