# How to use ObservableCollection with LiveChart2

Tags: c#, observablecollection, livecharts

How to use ObservableCollection with LiveCharts2

I am trying to implement LiveChart2 using ObservableCollection to update the chart everytime a new value is added.
The chart works fine if I add all the data at once but I am stuck in implementing "ObservableCollection".
Link to doc: https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/LiveCharts2/blob/master/docs/overview/1.4.automatic%20updates.md
I need help please. I have this code:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using LiveChartsCore;
using LiveChartsCore.Defaults;
using LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView;


namespace WpfSample
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public ISeries[] Series { get; set; }

       public ObservableCollection<ObservableValue> Series2 { get; set; }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            // This one is not working ///////////////////////////////////
            Series2 = new ObservableCollection<ObservableValue>();
            Series2.Add(new ObservableValue { Value = 1 });
            Series2.Add(new ObservableValue { Value = 2 });
            Series2.Add(new ObservableValue { Value = 3 });

            // every time you update the Value property, you will also see that change in the user interface
            Series2[0].Value = 5;


            // This one is working fine
            Series = new ISeries[]
            {
                new LineSeries<double>
                {
                    Values = new double[] { 6, 4, 3, 9, 4, 2, 1 },

                }
            };
             
            DataContext = this;
        }
    } 
}
```

```
<Window x:Class="WpfSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfSample"
        xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WPF;assembly=LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid>
        <lvc:CartesianChart 
            Series="{Binding Series}" Margin="4,4,433,174">
        </lvc:CartesianChart>
        <lvc:CartesianChart 
            Series="{Binding Series2}" Margin="403,0,0,177">
        </lvc:CartesianChart>

        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="728,318,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: can you show your xaml binding code ?

Comment: Yes, I added the xaml code

Comment: can you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44423768/binding-chart-to-data

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad Thank you, but that is an older version of LiveChart.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<ISeries> Series2 { get; set; }


private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{  
     Series2 = new ObservableCollection<ISeries>();
     Series2.Add(new LineSeries<double> { Values = new List<double> {1,2,3 } });
}
```